# How do I work with labels in VB 2010?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, variables, label

My name is Alex and I'm new to VB. I'm sorry but I am off topic. I just have one question : can anybody try to direct me to a link (or explain directly) in order to understand better how Visual Basic labels work? I need to understand what is the diference between a label and a variable and how we use labels. So far I have only used freebasic for some minor programming (build a small calculator etc.) and I would really apreciate your answer. Now I am using Visual Studio 2010 and I am following some tutorials that just give me the code without explaining how everything works. For example in building a calculator the tutorial used this code for the equal sign "=":

```
If Label2.Text > "" And Label2.Text = "+" Then 
    Button1.Text = Val(Label1.Text) + Val(Button1.Text) 
    Label3.Text = Button1.Text 
ElseIf Label2.Text > "" And Label2.Text = "-" Then 
    Button1.Text = Val(Label1.Text) - Val(Button1.Text) 
    Label3.Text = Button1.Text 
ElseIf Label2.Text > "" And Label2.Text = "*" Then 
    Button1.Text = Val(Label1.Text) * Val(Button1.Text) 
    Label3.Text = Button1.Text 
ElseIf Label2.Text > "" And Label2.Text = "/" Then 
    Button1.Text = Val(Label1.Text) / Val(Button1.Text) 
    Label3.Text = Button1.Text 
Else 
End If
```

Comment: [Getting Started with Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb466159) - might be a good place to start looking for a better tutorial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is that labels are for *displaying* information on the screen (your form). Variables are for storing information that you'll use later in your code.

In more depth, a `Label` is a type of *control*, much like a `TextBox` or a `Button`, it's just much lighter weight because it only *displays* text, rather than allows the user to interact with it. The user can edit the text in a `TextBox`, or click on a `Button`, but they can't do either of those things with a `Label`. You as the programmer control what information is displayed in a label.

A variable is exposed even less to the user. In fact, the end user of your program has no idea that you've used a variable at all, nor can they directly see any of the information that you've stored in it. It's *only* there for your use as the programmer. Think of it as a temporary holding facility for pieces of information. Behind the scenes, it's simply allocating a section of your computer's memory to store the value, and you can refer to that memory location using your variable's name (rather than some cryptic number).

So, what is the code that you've shown in your question doing? Well, before beginning that discussion, I must say that it's *awful* code. It's clearly not written with VB.NET (the current version, as included in Visual Studio 2010) in mind. I would *strongly* recommend that you find another tutorial (or better yet, pick up a book at your local bookstore) to learn VB.NET. Better to learn *good* practices when you first begin, rather than try to unlearn bad habits later.

Instead of using variables, the code is reading back in the values displayed on `Label` controls. I...I just don't even want to explain it any further because it's just such *bad* code. You should never write code that looks like that, so it's hardly worth worrying about. It *should* be using variables! And that, I assume,
is the source of your confusion.

**EDIT:** I don't see any related questions that have been answered here regarding book recommendations for a beginning VB.NET programmer. I generally hesitate to recommend books from my own experiences because I learned to program with the IDE on one monitor and the documentation on the other. I realize that's somewhat unusual, so I figure the books that I enjoy may not be helpful to "normal" people, either.

That being said, I later read "Mastering Visual Basic 2008" by Evangelos Petroutsos and was *very* impressed with the clarity of his explanations and the real-world applicability of his examples. He does a very good job of not assuming any prior knowledge in the beginning, but picking up speed as he goes along so that you actually learn something useful by the time you're finished reading the whole book.

I assume that the latest edition of his book, [Mastering Visual Basic 2010](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470532874), is as good as the previous edition that I read, so I highly recommend that you pick up a copy.

Comment: Thank you very much! You have really helped. So as I suspected labels shouldn't have been used here, the code would of been much easier to write using variables. I'll try to fiind "Mastering Visual Basic 2008".

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time to answer. I'll recommend this site to evryone I know. Have a nice day!

Comment: @Alex: Sure, not a problem. We were all beginners once! At some point, the system will allow you to "accept" my answer by clicking the hollow checkmark to the left. Make sure to do so if you found it helpful!